# Parsing and plotting GeoJSON in Google Maps v2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps, geojson

I have a nice big 27 MB geojson file lying on my SD Card. I has got a large number of features, geometry etc. 
As I was searching the web I didn't find any support for GeoJSON and Shape Files in Google Maps in Android natively. 
I want to plot all the geometry on the map (we can optimize it later to show some of the geometry) like point, line, polygon etc.

Do I need to write a parser on my own or did I fail to find support of geojson in Google Maps API for Android?

Comment: `Google Maps` not supported Shape Files directly. You should make your own `Parser` for that.

Comment: This can help you to parse GeoJson https://github.com/cocoahero/android-geojson . If you have found a solution then please do post

Answer (score 4):

Try using the Google Maps Android API utility library. It contains classes that will parse and handle your GeoJSON data. https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils