# Parsing And Plottng GeoJSON response in Android

Tags: android, maps, geojson

I have my custom GeoJSON response and want to parse and plot it into my android application. Which SDKs are available for that purpose and how to get started? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is old, but you can use this library: https://github.com/cocoahero/android-geojson to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Parsing and plotting GeoJSON in Google Maps v2 Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300904/parsing-and-plotting-geojson-in-google-maps-v2-android)

> Try using the Google Maps Android API utility library. It contains classes that will parse and handle your GeoJSON data. https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. But I dont want to use google maps. P'm using opensciencemap and want to display my oownGeoJSON data.